# My flex box items are not positioning where I want them to

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I am attempting to align the subheadings and body text on my webpage design (attached as a JPG) according to the specific locations I have indicated. I designed the page using Photoshop and am currently using pixel measurements to position the elements within a flex container in my CSS styles. However, I also want to implement a breakpoint that will alter the webpage's styling at a certain screen size. I am unsure if using pixel measurements is the best approach for this.[image: web page design]

```css
/*Universal selector-reset default*/
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Barlow, sans-serif;
}

/*nav flex box content*/
.navbar-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 64px;
    width: 1365px;
    background-color: #f9eaec;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.navbar {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#websiteName {
    color: black;
    font-style: Extrabold;
    font-size: 18px;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    height: 100%;
}

#logo {
    left: 62.3px;
    top: 6px;
}

.dropdown {
    top: 26px;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

/*body flex box content*/
.body-container {
    display: flex;
    height: 410px;
    width: 693px;
    margin: auto;
    transform: translateY(115.6px);
    border: 2px solid red;
}

#name {
    font-style: Extrabold;
    font-size: 59px;
    left: 339.8px;
    top: 179px;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    width: 276.2px;
}

#subname {
    font-style: Extrabold;
    font-size: 59px;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    width: 276.2px;
}

.subheading {
    font-style: Extrabold;
    font-size: 18px;
}

#subheadingOne {
    margin-left: 317px;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    width: 156px;
}

#subheadingTwo {
    margin-left: 561px;
    border: 2px solid blue;
}

#chemistryLab {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    top: 149px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 235px;
    width: 287.2px;
}

#down {
    padding-top: 1000px;
}

#translations {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    font-style: Thin;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-top: 61px;
    margin-left: 317px;
}

#definition {
    font-style: Thin;
    font-size: 14px;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    margin-top: 158px;
    margin-left: 317px;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
}

#dropdown-btn:checked~.dropdown-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    top: 23px;
    left: 1329px;
    align-content: space-between;
    gap: 20px;
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.search-box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 23px;
    left: 1197.8px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="periodictable.css">
  <title>EVERYTHING CHEMISTRY</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!--nav bar flex box-->
  <div class="navbar-container">
    <!--navbar general styling-->
    <div class="navbar">
      <!--navbar building blocks-->
      <h3 id='websiteName'>EVERYTHING CHEMISTRY</h3>
      <img id='logo' src="icon.png" alt="Hydrogen atom">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <input type="checkbox" id="dropdown-btn">
        <label for="dropdown-btn" class="dropbtn">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
        </label>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Home</a>
          <a href="#">About</a>
          <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>
        <!--search box-->
        <form class="search-box" action="action_page.php">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
          <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--body flex box-->
  <div class="body-container">
    <!--body general styling-->
    <div class="body">
      <div class="page-title">
        <h1 id='name'>Periodic</h1>
        <h1 id='subname'>Table</h1>
      </div>
      <img id='chemistryLab' src="Chemistry.JPG" alt="Chemist Lab">
      <div class="subheading">
        <h2 id='subheadingOne'>118 Elements</h2>
        <h2 id='subheadingTwo'>7 Periods</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="body-text">
        <p id='translations'>{Eng: Periodic Table; Arabic: الجدول الدوري; Afrikaans: Periodieke tabel; Mandarin: 周期表
          (zhōuqī biǎo); Urdu: پیرودیک ٹیبل.}</p>
        <p id='definition'>The periodic table is a tabular arrangement of the chemical elements, organized on the basis
          of their atomic number, electron configurations, and chemical properties. Elements are presented in rows
          (called periods) and columns (called groups or families) according to their increasing atomic number. The
          elements in a group have similar chemical and physical properties, and those in a period show a progression
          of properties as the atomic number increases. The table provides a useful summary of the properties of the
          elements and their chemical reactivity. It is widely used in chemistry and other sciences to predict the
          properties and behavior of elements and their compounds.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <aside class="move-down"><a href="#down"><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down"></i></a>
  </aside>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you have to align items using flex you must make the parent or container itself a flex in your case is subheading class. Which I don't think you do in your codes. Also the margin left and right in the subheadingOne and subheadingTwo is not supposed to be there since you using flex to align items.
So the codes should be like this

```
.subheading {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    font-style: Extrabold;
    font-size: 18px;
}

#subheadingOne {
     border: 2px solid blue;
     width: 156px;
 }

#subheadingTwo {
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
```